# PHP Table Parsing Script Only Selects the First Table it Sees

Tags: php, html, html-table, html-parsing

I'm using a PHP script to parse a HTML table into an array. But I'm running into an issue, the page I'm trying to parse has 3 tables on the page, and the script only selects the first table it sees. Is there any way I could make it so it will parse every table it sees or just the 3rd table?

```
function parseTable($html)
{
    // Find the table
    preg_match("/<table.*?>.*?<\/[\s]*table>/s", $html, $table_html);

    // Get title for each row
    preg_match_all("/<th.*?>(.*?)<\/[\s]*th>/", $table_html[0], $matches);
    $row_headers = $matches[1];

    // Iterate each row
    preg_match_all("/<tr.*?>(.*?)<\/[\s]*tr>/s", $table_html[0], $matches);

    $table = array();

    foreach($matches[1] as $row_html)
    {
        preg_match_all("/<td.*?>(.*?)<\/[\s]*td>/", $row_html, $td_matches);
        $row = array();

        for($i=0; $i<count($td_matches[1]); $i++)
        {
            $td = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($td_matches[1][$i]));
            $row[$row_headers[$i]] = $td;
        }

        if(count($row) > 0)
        {
            $table[] = $row;
        }
    }

    return $table;
}
```

Comment: Use preg_match_all() for your table matching expression, like you are already doing for the headers, rows and cells.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this updated version of your function returns an array of tables:

```
function parseTable($html)
{
    // Find the table
    preg_match_all("/<table.*?>.*?<\/[\s]*table>/s", $html, $tablesMatches);
    $tables = array();
    foreach ($tablesMatches[0] as $table_html) {

        // Get title for each row
        preg_match_all("/<th.*?>(.*?)<\/[\s]*th>/", $table_html, $matches);
        $row_headers = $matches[1];

        // Iterate each row
        preg_match_all("/<tr.*?>(.*?)<\/[\s]*tr>/s", $table_html, $matches);

        $table = array();

        foreach ($matches[1] as $row_html)
        {
            preg_match_all("/<td.*?>(.*?)<\/[\s]*td>/", $row_html, $td_matches);
            $row = array();
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($td_matches[1]); $i++)
            {
                $td = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($td_matches[1][$i]));
                $row[$row_headers[$i]] = $td;
            }

            if (count($row) > 0)
                $table[] = $row;
        }

        $tables[] = $table;
    }

    return $tables;
}
```

Comment: Update to foreach() loop, have to loop over $tablesMatches[0].

Answer (score 0):

`preg_match` command stops itself when the first occurrence is found, as you do later in the code use the `preg_match_all` and iterate over all the matches.

Comment: Could I store each table in a seperate array

Comment: sure, just add as third param $tables and iterate over that.